# Google Forms Edit Link Issue

Tags: forms, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

In Google Sheets, I am having an issue with the following code:

```
function assignEditUrls() {
  var form = FormApp.openById('Google-Form-ID-Goes-Here');

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet-Name-Goes-Here');

  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var urlCol = 7; 
  var responses = form.getResponses();
  var timestamps = [], urls = [], resultUrls = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < responses.length; i++) {
    timestamps.push(responses[i].getTimestamp().setMilliseconds(0));
    urls.push(responses[i].getEditResponseUrl());
  }
  for (var j = 1; j < data.length; j++) {

    resultUrls.push([data[j][0]?urls[timestamps.indexOf(data[j][0].setMilliseconds(0))]:'']);
  }
  sheet.getRange(2, urlCol, resultUrls.length).setValues(resultUrls);  
}
```

The problem I am having is, after I set the Form ID and Sheet name, I get the following error:

> TypeError: Cannot find function setMilliseconds in object FormQId.
>   (line 17, file "Code")

Which is the following:

```
    resultUrls.push([data[j][0]?urls[timestamps.indexOf(data[j][0].setMilliseconds(0))]:'']);
```

I am by no means a genius, I have no clue on how or where to start troubleshooting.

Comment: Is `data[j][0]` a Date or a String? If it's a string then there is no setMilliseconds() function in the string class. Apparently timestamps is a Date Object.

Comment: Not sure, to be honest, the code comes from here but I am not sure what that does. https://digitalegghead.com/index.php/2018/03/06/edit-google-form-responses/